# move built jar over ssh to the remote server

Tags: ssh, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I'm new in jenking and continious integration.

***What I need:***

I want to push my jar file to the remote server after build.

***What a problem:***

But I can't find any shh credentials configs in Jenkins. I've read that I need to install  *Publish_Over_Shh_Plugin*, BUT as I understand I can't. (means I can't beacause jenkins is installed on the remote server and I heven't rights to do that)

***Questions:***

Is it possible to set SSH credential without installing *Publish_Over_Shh_Plugin*?

Answer (score 0):

If ssh is available to the Jenkins user (that is the user account that Jenkins runs under) you should be able to add a post build step.

This answer sounds vague, but I don't anything about your setup (What OS? What plugins installed? ...) except that Jenkins is installed on a remote machine and for some unknown reason you can't get someone to install the needed plugin for you.